# Distribute JavaScript number with varying remainder

Tags: javascript, math

Imaging the following case: The number (`10.03`) should be distributed by `3`. In plain JavaScript, this would result in `3,3433333333` each.
What I ideally want is a solution that outputs an array of 3 elements that contains the following values:

```
[ 3.34, 3.34, 3.35 ]
```

I can't get my head around this. What I tried:

```
const a = 10.03;
const b = 3;
const dist = [];

for (let i = 0; i < b; i++) {
    dist.push((a / b).toFixed(2));
}
```

Output:

```
[3.34, 3.34, 3.34]
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Round to two digits, distribute the differences onto the last elements.

Comment: But you want some kind of an algorithm that can cope with any division? Or only for this special case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Updated:

Here's a newer version that distributes the remainder in a more even manner as suggested by @Bergi. The magnitude depends on the larger of `minDecimalPlaces` or the precision of `dividend`;

**EDIT**: Improved for performance by @Bergi

```js
function distributedDivision(dividend, divisor, minDecimalPlaces) {
  const decimalPlaces = Math.max(
    minDecimalPlaces,
    (dividend + '.').toString().split('.')[1].length
  );
  const magnitude = Math.pow(10, decimalPlaces);
  const quotient = Math.floor((dividend * magnitude) / divisor);
  const result = Array(divisor).fill(quotient);
  let i = 0;
  for (
    let remainder = Math.floor((dividend * magnitude) % divisor);
    remainder > 0;
    remainder--
  ) {
    result[i]++;
    i++;
  }
  return result.map(v => Math.round(v) / magnitude);
}

console.log(distributedDivision(10.10, 4, 2));
```

I'm assuming what you want is a division function that limits the quotients to some number of decimal places?

You can do something like this:

```js
function distributedDivision(dividend, divisor, maxDecimalPlaces) {
  const magnitude = Math.pow(10,maxDecimalPlaces);
  const lesser = Math.round((dividend*magnitude)/divisor)/magnitude;
  return (new Array(divisor-1)).fill(lesser).concat(Math.round((dividend-(lesser*(divisor-1)))*magnitude)/magnitude);
}

console.log(distributedDivision(10.03,3,2));
console.log(distributedDivision(10.04,3,2));
console.log(distributedDivision(10.07,4,2));
```

**EDIT:** One requirement is that `maxDecimalPlaces` be at least as large as the number of decimals in `dividend`

Comment: This is the one. Great algorithm and usage of native language features, thank you!

Comment: I don't think this works as intended for divisors greater than 3, e.g. `distributedDivision(10.10,4,2)`

Comment: @Bergi the result I'm getting is `[ 2.53, 2.53, 2.53, 2.51 ]` which sums to `10.1`. What's wrong with that?

Comment: @rovyko I'm not the OP, but I would have expected `[2.52, 2.52, 2.53, 2.53]` (in any order).

Comment: @Bergi - That's a good point. I'll think about how that can be implemented.

Comment: @rovyko Thanks, that's what I was looking for! I would however recommend to leave out the `/magnitude` for `quotient` and `remainder`, then do the distribution of the remainder on integers (with `cursor = 1`) and only in the end (in the `map`) do the division. That means you can leave out all the `Math.round` calls on integers. Btw I'm pretty sure you can do just `result[i]`, no need for `%divisor`.

Comment: @Bergi - Those are really good points, thanks for your feedback. I've made the relevant edits.